# Promoter badge with all questions

Tags: support, badges, bounty

I want to provide a bounty for one of my questions.

Because it is the first time I do this, I also want to earn the "Promoter" badge.

As described in the badge:

> First bounty you offer on your own question

But when I try to search my questions with the 'Go get it >' button, I only found questions with this filter:

```
is:question answers:0 user:[userId] closed:no score:1 created:..2018-12-10
```

Isn't this badge supposed to work with all questions with no previous bounty offered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This search is apparently trying to optimize the success rate of the bounty. These parameters are required:

- `is:question`
- `user:me`
- `closed:no`
- `created:..2018-12-10` (you can only offer bounties on questions which are more than 48 hours old; this is the best the search options can offer)

These parameters are optional (if you remove them, you still get only questions on which you can earn the badge):

- `answers:0` if you already got an answer, chances are you don't need a bounty anymore.
- `score:1` a question without positive reception isn't likely to be a good question, so it's less likely to attract a good, bounty-worthy answer.

Comment: `created:..3d` is more portable.

Comment: Interestingly, I think all the bounties I've offered were to reward existing answers that had gone "above and beyond".

Comment: I agree with @MatthieuM.'s point; there are numerous purposes to a bounty, only one of which is "I haven't gotten an answer yet and would like to draw attention". Likewise I don't agree that a question with a score less than 1 is necessarily bad--it could have simply been more along the lines of Tumbleweed badge criteria (low views).